# How to use Partial View?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I haven't often used partial views but I do understand the basics but I have a problem.

I have a master page with a Modal form on. In this modal form I would like to use a partial view to render both an image and a footer. However, I need to manually write in a header and the body content. So basically it would look like this:

Partial View:

-Image-
-Content I want to write-
-Footer-

However, whenever I try to do this and include things such as render Body or render section, it does not work. Does anybody have any ideas on how I can do this?

Modal:

```
  <div id="helpModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    @Html.Partial("ModalLayoutPartial")           
                    <h1 style="text-align:center"> HELP </h1>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Help help helperton</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Partial View:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <img src="~/Content/Images/Logo/ap_tick_green.png" />
</div>
<body>

</body>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#">Need more help? Contact us here.</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry but can you please expand on your question. I do not understand what the problem is?

Comment: The problem is that I cannot use RenderBody or RenderSection, I get the following error:   The file "~/Views/Shared/ModalLayoutPartial.cshtml" cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderSection" method.

Comment: I believe this is because I am using @section on a master page and then trying to render a section on a partial view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a model into the partial so in your case make the model a string:

```
@Html.Partial("ModalLayoutPartial", "text to show")
```

Then in your partial declare the model (and use it):

```
@model string

<div class="modal-header">
    <img src="~/Content/Images/Logo/ap_tick_green.png" />
</div>
<body>
    @Html.Raw(Model)
</body>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#">Need more help? Contact us here.</a>
</div>
```

Please note you shouldn't use body tag in the above - [a html document should only have one body tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body)

Or you could pass in a class:

```
public class ModalInfo
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Then call your partial:

```
@Html.Partial("ModalLayoutPartial", new ModalInfo() { Title = "HELP", Body = "Help help helperton" })
```

Show your partial

```
@model ModalInfo

<div class="modal-header">
    <img src="~/Content/Images/Logo/ap_tick_green.png" />
</div>
<div class="body">
    <h1 style="text-align:center">@Model.Title</h1>
    <div class="modal-body">
       <p>@Model.Body</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#">Need more help? Contact us here.</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer, however I would now how to use my model on every single  View I have now or it fails. I think I'm just going to hard code the modal forms. There arent too many. Thanks though